# What is practical limits on limit increase of number of AWS instances per region/account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

As I know by default you are limited to have up to 20 on demand instances in region.
You can ask amazon to increase it. Did anyone do it? How many instances can you theoretically have? Is it 100 per region? 1000? 10k?
Is there any info on how much instances AWS have in sum?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the actual "rule" is, but realistically, AWS will give you access to 5x-10x what you are currently *using*. If you ask for a large increase they may deny you because your bill is too small (so a huge increase seems like fraud) or because you are requesting too many for the current capacity of the region.

In the latter case, they'll often approve larger numbers of Spot instances.